# Google Script - Take on array several cell values at same time

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've developed a script, but it is TOOOOO slow (>1min). I've read that less calls to take values reduces that time, so I'd ask how to do that. The idea is to take the cell values on just one single line, and then for each "let", take one part of that array.

Do you know how to do that? The code is this:

```
function createPDF() {
  
  const currentSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("CRM");

  let profe_nombre = currentSheet.getRange(14,40).getValues();
  let profe_direccion = currentSheet.getRange(16,40).getValues();
  let profe_dni = currentSheet.getRange(15,40).getValues();
  let profe_iban = currentSheet.getRange(17,40).getValues();
  let profe_paypal = currentSheet.getRange(18,40).getValues();
  let profe_email = currentSheet.getRange(19,40).getValues();
  let factura_nombre = currentSheet.getRange(26,39).getValues();
  let factura_fecha = currentSheet.getRange(23,40).getDisplayValues();
  let factura_importe = currentSheet.getRange(22,40).getValues();
  let factura_notas = currentSheet.getRange(26,38).getValues();

  const docFile = DriveApp.getFileById("sheetID");
  const tempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("folderID");
  const pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("folderID");
  const tempFile = docFile.makeCopy(tempFolder);
  const tempDocFile = DocumentApp.openById(tempFile.getId());
  const body = tempDocFile.getBody()
  body.replaceText("{profe_nombre}", profe_nombre);
  body.replaceText("{profe_direccion}", profe_direccion);
  body.replaceText("{profe_dni}", profe_dni);
  body.replaceText("{profe_iban}", profe_iban);
  body.replaceText("{profe_paypal}", profe_paypal);
  body.replaceText("{profe_email}", profe_email);
  body.replaceText("{factura_nombre}", factura_nombre);
  body.replaceText("{factura_fecha}", factura_fecha);
  body.replaceText("{factura_importe}", factura_importe);
  body.replaceText("{factura_notas}", factura_notas);
  tempDocFile.saveAndClose();
  const pdfContentBlob = tempFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
  pdfFolder.createFile(pdfContentBlob).setName(factura_nombre + ".pdf");
  tempFolder.removeFile(tempFile);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Factura creada");

}

function apendiceRemesa() {

  const SheetCRM = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("CRM");
  const SheetRemesas = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Remesas");
  
  let remesa_cuenta = SheetCRM.getRange(17,40).getValue();
  let remesa_importe = SheetCRM.getRange(22,40).getValue();
  let remesa_nombre = SheetCRM.getRange(14,40).getValue();
  let remesa_concepto = SheetCRM.getRange(26,39).getValue();
  const remesa_estado_pago = SheetCRM.getRange(24,40).getValue();
  let remesa_estado_pago_fila = SheetCRM.getRange(23,43).getValue();
  let remesa_estado_pago_columna = SheetCRM.getRange(24,43).getValue();

  if (remesa_estado_pago == 'P') {
    SheetRemesas.appendRow([remesa_cuenta,remesa_importe,remesa_nombre,remesa_concepto]);
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(remesa_estado_pago_fila, remesa_estado_pago_columna).setValue('RM');
    
  } else {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('ERROR. Esta factura ya fue pagada')
  }
  

}
```

I've separated both functions because I have two different buttons for each, so it is not mandatory to first execute createPDF and then apendiceRemesa (I will develop a new function too for both functions, removing some redundant variables then).

Thank you!

**%%% UPDATE %%%**

Yuri and Iamblichus sokution have reduced about 20% of the execution time. Now, I wonder if there is any other way to identify the worksheet name:

From

```
const currentSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("CRM");

const data = currentSheet.getRange('al8:ar26').getDisplayValues();
```

To something like this:

```
const data = getRange("CRM!AL8:AR26").getDisplayValues();
```

Comment: If it was > 1 min and now it's about 35 sec the improvement is much more than 20% )

Comment: The next step of optimization would be to learn to use Sheets API.

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution:

- First, retrieve a range containing all your desired values. A simple option would be to use [getDataRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange), which will simply get a range corresponding to all sheet values.
- Then, retrieve the different desired values from the resulting 2D array, using the corresponding indexes (first row index, then column index). It's important to note that arrays are 0-indexed, contrasting with the 1-indexed parameters from `getRange`, so you'll have to subtract 1 to each index.

#### Sample:

To show you how it's done, here's a sample that retrieves the first variables:

```
const values = currentSheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
const profe_nombre = values[13][39];
const profe_direccion = values[15][39];
const profe_dni = values[14][39];
// ...and so on...
```

**Note**: If the cells were more contiguous with each other, I would recommend [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to accomplish this with fewer lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to get all data from the sheet as a 2d array and then get 'cells' from the array, not directly from the sheet.

Instead of this:

```
let profe_nombre    = currentSheet.getRange(14,40).getValues();
let profe_direccion = currentSheet.getRange(16,40).getValues();
let profe_dni       = currentSheet.getRange(15,40).getValues();
let profe_iban      = currentSheet.getRange(17,40).getValues();
let profe_paypal    = currentSheet.getRange(18,40).getValues();
let profe_email     = currentSheet.getRange(19,40).getValues();
let factura_nombre  = currentSheet.getRange(26,39).getValues();
let factura_fecha   = currentSheet.getRange(23,40).getDisplayValues();
let factura_importe = currentSheet.getRange(22,40).getValues();
let factura_notas   = currentSheet.getRange(26,38).getValues();
```

Try this:

```
const data = currentSheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues(); // the 2d array

// take values from the array
let profe_nombre    = data[13][39];
let profe_direccion = data[15][39];
let profe_dni       = data[14][39];
let profe_iban      = data[16][39];
let profe_paypal    = data[17][39];
let profe_email     = data[18][39];
let factura_nombre  = data[25][38];
let factura_fecha   = data[22][39];
let factura_importe = data[21][39];
let factura_notas   = data[23][37];
```

Etc.

For your second function `apendiceRemesa()`:

```
const data = SheetCRM.getDataRange().getValues();
let remesa_cuenta              = data[16][39];
let remesa_importe             = data[21][39];
let remesa_nombre              = data[13][39];
let remesa_concepto            = data[25][38];
const remesa_estado_pago       = data[23][39];
let remesa_estado_pago_fila    = data[22][42];
let remesa_estado_pago_columna = data[23][42];
```

Comment: Thank you guys! Yuri Khristich @Iamblichus 


I've tried that change, but it doesn't get properly the data. i.e in the cell AN40, that would be data[23,39], there is just a formula that gets the value "Re". But when I pint the value, I get a long array from the row 40.

I print the msg via this to test it:

SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(remesa_estado_pago)

Do you know what am I doing wrong??

Comment: _in the cell AN40, that would be data[23,39]_ -- `AN40` it equal `data[39,39]` (if your cell A1, or row 1, or column A aren't empty)

Comment: Hi yuri! I'm sorry but I can't get what you mean. In my worksheet, A1 cell isn't empty, but I donk't know how is the relation between other empty cells and the actual cell I'm trying to get the value (AN40).

Comment: Sorry, my bad. In the code it should be `data[13][19]` not `data[13,19]`. Etc. Just fixed it. `AN40` will be `data[39][39]`. The first number is a row index, the second number is a column index.

Comment: A1 --> [0][0], A2 --> [1][0], A3 -->[2][0], B1 --> [0][1], B2 --> [1][1], B3 --> [2][1], ...etc.

Comment: Thank you! Now it works perfectly. However, the execution time is still slow af... 20 secs for the first function and 15 sec for the 2nd one. Would be any way to speed it up (as it is a very simple and light code)

Comment: Did you make the same changes in your second function `apendiceRemesa()`? I just added it in my answer

Comment: If your sheet has a huge amount of texts it can take a long time to get all the data with `getDataRange().getValues()`. In this case it makes sense to try to grab a part of the sheet. In your case it will be the rectangle from row13/col38 to row26/col40. But it will need to recalculate col and row indexes in the 2d array. The cell (13,38) will be `data[0][0]` etc.

Comment: Thank you Yuri. Yes, that would be great, because I have thousands of rows there (it is a database). So I'd just have to replace the empty () for getDataRange(AM10:AQ26).getValues(AM10:AQ26) ?

Comment: `var data = currentSheet.getRange('am10:aq26').getValues()` something like this. I don't know how your sheet looks like. It's up to you to select the minimal correct range.

Comment: Great! I've tried it and it saves a couple of seconds :) Keeping on the time reduction, I'm going to edit the root topic, because maybe we can keep on the time reduction (please see main text)